# « Il s’est instruit tout seul en lisant » ou « Il s’est instruit tout seul par la lecture »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation, reformulation

> Il s’est instruit tout seul en lisant des oeuvres de toutes sortes.

> Il s’est instruit tout seul par la lecture.

Laquelle est meilleure?

Si vous avez d’autres propositions à m’offrir, faites-les-moi connaître!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C'est un autodidacte, instruit par ses lectures variées.